# Find lines that contain certain text, and print what follows that text

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am trying to get SQL statements from Hive output via this shell command:

```
tail -f /var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log | grep "Parsing command"
```

However, this gives me the full line:

```
2018-03-18 03:07:57,689 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-13816]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(190)) - Parsing command: SELECT * from table
```

I would like to grep but remove the front portion to just show this:

```
SELECT * from table
```

Is there a way to do this in a one-liner by searching for `Parsing command:` and keeping the part of the line after that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just swap your `grep` with `awk` to get subset of line you're looking for:

```
tail -f /var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log |
awk -F "Parsing command: " '{print $2}'
```

```
SELECT * from table
```

`-F "Parsing command: "` makes `"Parsing command: "` field separator for `awk` command and `$2` gives as substring after this marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f /var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log | sed -n '/Parsing command/{s/^.*Parsing command:\s*//;p}'
```

- `sed -n`: don't print lines by default.
- `/Parsing command/{...}`: Do the things in `{}` for every line that matches `Parsing command`
- `s/^.*Parsing command:\s*//`: get rid of everything from the start of the line (`^`) up to `Parsing command:`.  Also get rid of any whitespace after the colon (`\s*`)
- `p`: Print the modified line.

#### Test file (`foo.txt`):

```
2018-03-18 03:07:57,689 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-13816]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(190)) - Parsing command: SELECT * from table
foo
Parsing command: other command
bar
2018-03-18 03:07:57,689 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-13816]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(190)) - Something else
```

#### Test:

```
$ sed -n '/Parsing command/{s/^.*Parsing command:\s*//;p}' < foo.txt
SELECT * from table
other command
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can also use grep:

`grep -Po 'Parsing command: \K.*'`

The `\K` resets the match to start after the `\K`. `-P`is for perl regexp, because regular grep regexp doesn't have`\K`.`-o` prints only the matched part.